# Promisse filha não está entrando no catch do pai

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho esse método genérico que recupera algo do servidor:

```
async criate(url: string, object: Object): Promise<any> {
    try {
        return response = await this.api().post( url, object );

    } catch (error) {
        console.log( 'API_ERROR: ', error.request.response, 'CODE: ', error.request.status );
    }
}
```

Tenho esse model que consome o método acima:

```
async login() {
        this.loading = true;

        try {
            const user: User = await this.api.cri<User>(rotaUsuario.login, this.currentUser);

        } catch (e) {
            console.log( e );

        } finally {
            this.loading = false;
        }
    }
```

E por fim o componente que consome o dado:

```
this.store.login().then(() => this.navigation.navigate('Sessao')).catch(() => console.log('error'));
```

O problema é que quando o método genérico  entra no `catch` mesmo assim o componente que consome chama o `then` ao invés de chamar o `catch` como eu espero. 
Como consertar isso?

Answer (score 0):

Rafael,

Isso ocorre por conta de seus métodos não lançarem a exceção.

Você pode corrigir fazendo o throw de algum erro customizado ou lançar a própria exceção capturada no catch.

Veja um exemplo de erros com funções assíncronas:

```js
//Dessa forma não funciona, pois você acaba não retornando a exceção
async function maiorQueZero(value) {
  try {
    if (value > 0) {
      return value;
    }
    else {
      return funcao_nao_existe(value);
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    //Acaba não retornando nada
    //Ou console.log
  }
}

//Dessa forma funciona, pois é feito o reject na promise
async function maiorIgualZero(value) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      if (value >= 0) {
        resolve(value);
      }
      else {
        resolve(funcao_nao_existe(value));
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
      //Rejeita a promise...
      reject(e);
    }
  });
}

//Dessa forma também funciona, pois é lançada a exceção na função
async function menorIgualZero(value) {
  try {
    if (value <= 0) {
      return value;
    }
    else {
      return funcao_nao_existe(value);
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    //Faz qualquer coisa aqui e lança a exceção
    throw e;
  }
}

//Essas utilizações não vão cair no catch
maiorQueZero(10)
  .then( result => console.log("maiorQueZero(10) = Não gerou erro") )
  .catch( error => console.log("maiorQueZero(10) = Gerou erro"));

//Deveria cair no catch, mas não vai cair...
maiorQueZero(0)
  .then( result => console.log("maiorQueZero(0) = Não gerou erro") )
  .catch( error => console.log("maiorQueZero(0) = Gerou erro"));

//Essas formas já caem no catch por conta do reject da promise
maiorIgualZero(0)
  .then( result => console.log("maiorIgualZero(0) = Não gerou erro") )
  .catch( error => console.log("maiorIgualZero(0) = Gerou erro"));

//Deve cair no catch
maiorIgualZero(-1)
  .then( result => console.log("maiorIgualZero(-1) = Não gerou erro") )
  .catch( error => console.log("maiorIgualZero(-1) = Gerou erro"));

//Essas formas também vão cair no catch por conta do thorw da exceção
menorIgualZero(0)
  .then( result => console.log("menorIgualZero(0) = Não gerou erro") )
  .catch( error => console.log("menorIgualZero(0) = Gerou erro"));

//Deve cair no catch
menorIgualZero(1)
  .then( result => console.log("menorIgualZero(1) = Não gerou erro") )
  .catch( error => console.log("menorIgualZero(1) = Gerou erro"));
```

Portanto, uma possível correção em seu código, seria a seguinte:

```
async criate(url: string, object: Object): Promise<any> {
    try {
        return response = await this.api().post( url, object );

    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("API_ERROR: " + error.request.response + " CODE: " + error.request.status );
    }
}

async login() {
    this.loading = true;

    try {
        const user: User = await this.api.cri<User>(rotaUsuario.login, this.currentUser);

    } catch (e) {
        throw e;

    } finally {
        this.loading = false;
    }
}
```